# Pandas Data Frame Statistics - aggregation and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DF composed of the following columns:

[image: Overview_excell_sheet]

While converted to Excell, it is supposed to give an overview of the existing EC2 instances in my AWS Account.

I wanted to create another summary sheet, in which I would list the total of running and stopped instances, pro type and availability zone.

I started with the following code:

```
summary = ec2_list.groupby('State').agg({'InstanceId':"count"})
```

the output is :

```
State                                                     
running  i-0e66a7b2972eb9dc1i-0bdb131da3764d0d8i-0111e0...
stopped  i-09d8cc76c65c77711i-0b2ab7e36895233e8i-04285b...
```

while I was expecting a count of instance IDs, I only receive a listing of instance IDs.

While converting it to excell, with this code:

```
summary = ec2_list.groupby('State').agg({'InstanceId':"count"}).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'ec2summary', startrow=0, startcol=0, index=False)
```

I also only get a single column with a listing of instance IDs.

can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is count and not `sum` ?

Comment: both have delivered the same result

Comment: Can you add some sample data in dict? `print (ec2_list.head().to_dict())`

Comment: Because very weird `count` and `sum` working same. Never seen before.

Comment: It worked, but I still can't see the full result in Excell after trying to execute .toexcell() .....